# Wordpress site doesn’t render as expected

Tags: wordpress

I decided to give wp ago, thought it would save time from writing custom html, css and js.

For the most part it has, however, how the page renders in my admin page compared to live is very different.

Because it’s rendering in admin as expected I’m finding it difficult to correct the display issues.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: We're not next to you therefore can't see what's is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the domain name in the URL when your are logged as admin to the domain name when you are live.
If you create your WP at first time in a development URL then moves  to a different server it will not be able to find CSS files what causes wrong rendering.